# Develop a loop with two counters

Tags: programming

**Description:**

I am trying to develop a function that would take two arguments `n` and `m` and would run another function multiple times with varied arguments; the first argument would vary from `1` to `n` and the second argument would vary from `n+1` to `m`.

**Example:**

```
n = 2  
m = 6

f @@ {n,m}

g[1,3], g[1,4], g[1,5], g[1,6], 
g[2,3], g[2,4], ...
```

How could I achieve the above?

Here is what I have tried:

```
f[n_, m_ ] := For[j = 1, j <= n, j++, 
 For[J = n, J <= m, J++, x[j_, J_] = Subscript[r, j, J]/1]; 
 Print[x[j, J]]]
```

`x[j_, J_] = Subscript[r, j, J]/1` corresponds to `g` in the first example.

Comment: You should avoid `Subscript`, instead of `Subscript[a,b]` use `a[b]`. Here I think you want `Table[x[i,j], {i, n}, {j, n+1, m}]`.

Comment: This this my real pregramation  ,For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, 
 For[J = 4, J <= 6, J++, x[j_, J_] = Subscript[r, j, J]/1]; 
 Print[x[j, J]]                                                                                           , Subscripts are just notation.  Note, that I´m programing a loop inside another one.

Comment: Also, avoid `For` and try using [`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) or [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html); they have the same functionality and are significantly faster than `For`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `1` in `Subscript[r, j, J]/1`? _Mathematica_ automatically simplifies the expression, and `/1` disappears when `Set (=)` is evaluated.

Comment: Yeah, I know, and it is because into  denominator I have a sum tha runs from j=1 to 3, but now, I need to get these all  combination, the sum ins´t problem,

Comment: @FranciscoVillegas regarding expected output, does the last edit represented the expected result correctly?

Comment: Could you clarify what `x[j_, J_] = Subscript[r, j, J]/1` means? Are you trying to define a function, as in `x[j_, J_] := Subscript[r, j, J]/1`? Or, are you trying to set values to several `x[j, J]`s, as in `x[j, J] = Subscript[r, j, J]/1`? [`Blank (_)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) and [`SetDelayed (:=)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) can make a lot of difference. With what you have currently, any `x[j, J]` would yield `x[n,m]`.

Comment: Well, I´m going to clarify it. Subscript[x, j, J] = Subscript[r, j, J]/\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(n\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(j, J\)]\). This is my real problem. So, that I am trying is to define all fuctions that I can get when I fix this subscripts, so the numer of functions that  I´m going to have it´s going to be determined by "j", So if I fix j sart to 1 to n, and J start n+1 to m, I need n ecuations. and this ecuations are going to be, if i supose endings of n=2, m=4, x[1,3] x[1,4], x[2,3], x[2,4]. for thar reason I´m using a loop, to define all this fucntions

Comment: @E.Doroskevic, the real problem that I have, is defining the function "f´s" according with the values of subscripts.

Comment: @FranciscoVillegas this is not clearly communicated in yor OP or all edits that have been done by the community members; so it is rather difficult to help you find a solution to your problem

Comment: Do you realize when you do `x[j_, J_]` those (underscored) variables are local to the function (that is unrelated to the `j,J` you use for `For` loop indexing)? The `j,J` on the right hand side of that expression are however the loop quantities.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, make `Mathematica` automatically create variables when they are called (Memoization). You don't need a loop for that.

```
x[i_, j_] := x[i, j] = Subscript[r, i, j]/1
```

If you need a loop, use `Do`:

```
n = 2;
m = 6;
Do[x[i, j] = Subscript[r, i, j]/1, {i, n}, {j, n+1, m}]
```

```
x[2, 5]

(* Subscript[r, 2, 5] *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, please see implementation below.

**Example:**

```
x[n_, m_] := Outer[f, Range[n], Range[n+1, m]]
x[2,6]
```

**Note:** `f` is an arbitrary function which takes two arguments

**Output:**

> {{f[1, 3], f[1, 4], f[1, 5], f[1, 6]}, {f[2, 3], f[2, 4], f[2, 5],
>   f[2, 6]}}

Comment: Yeah, but waht I try to do is define each function whit thiss loop.                     For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, 
 For[J = 4, J <= 6, J++, x[j_, J_] = Subscript[r, j, J]/\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(4\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(j, J\)]\)]; Print[x[j, k]]]

Comment: Please edit your question, at this rate it's not clare what you are after